# Monocle view only appending one list for all lists on the database

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I am using Monocle MVC with Quojs and Lungo.

I am trying to create a `select` tag filled with the current user lists. To do so, I iterate through the users lists and for each one, I append a `option` tag inside the `select`.

In order to manage the change in lists, I empty the `select`, create a default option (all lists) and then append like I described previously.

The problem is I only get one list appended, the last one in my model.

Here is my code :

```
$$('.sort-by-list').empty()
$$('.sort-by-list').append('<option value="all">Select a list</option>')

view_sort = new __View.SortByList model: list
view_sort.append list for list in __Model.List.all()
```

The `new __View...` is defined this way :

```
class __View.SortByList extends Monocle.View

  container: '.sort-by-list'

  template: """
    <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
    """
```

Shouldn't the call to `view_sort.append` add an `option` tag for all the lists in the database?

**UPDATE**

If I remove the `empty()` call on '.sort-by-list', the view appends all the lists in the model (all lists get a `option` tag, but if I remove a list from the model, for example, it will still be in the select. That's why I must empty the list before refilling it.